# Should I use 'Told' instead of 'Said' in the following Indirect Narration Speech?

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting, direct-speech

> 1. My classmate **said** to me,"Good morning,You have finished your homework".
> 2. My classmate wished me good morning and **told** me/**said** that I had finished my homework.

which is appropriate to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely up to you.  The first is an example of direct quoting, the second is reported speech. Both are common, both are correct. In the second example you could use either "told me that..." or "said that ...". Both are correct.